# If $D(f) = \{P \in T : \iota^{-1}(P) \in V\},$ there exists $A \subseteq S$ such that $V = \bigcup\limits_{a \in A} D(a).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\iota$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-linear endomorphism of $S = \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ given by $\iota(x) = x^2, \iota(y) = y^3, \iota(z) = z^4.$ Let $T$ be the set of homogeneous prime ideals, let $U$ be those which are homogeneous if $x, y, z$ are assigned degree $2, 3, 4$ respectively. For $f \in S,$ define $$D_T(f) = \{P \in T : f \not\in P\}, D_U(f) = \{P \in U : f \not\in P\}.$$

> Suppose $V \subseteq U$ and $D_T(f) = \{P \in T : \iota^{-1}(P) \in V\},$ prove there exists $A \subseteq S$ such that $V = \bigcup\limits_{a \in A} D_U(a).$

I haven't been able to guess what $A$ should be, even for a simple example like $f = x^2+y^2+z^2.$ The problem is that we have no info on $V$ or $f,$ just that they happen to be related by the given equation.

Comment: Kind of weird because for homogeneous $P$, $i^{-1}(P)$ is not typically homogeneous any more. (And conversely, if $i^{-1}(P)$ is homogeneous, typically $P$ isn’t.) Are you sure you’ve stated the problem correctly?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Fixed, I mixed up 2 different definitions of homogeneous.

Comment: Ah okay. For a polynomial $h$ and integer $k$ let $h_k$ be the degree $k$ homogeneous piece of $h$ (so $h_k$ is homogeneous of degree $k$ and $h=\sum_k h_k$). For a homogeneous ideal $J$, $h \notin J$ if and only if some $h_k \notin J$. Apply this to $g=i(f)$ with the changed grading. I hope this helps!

Comment: To be explicit I’m proposing that $A$ is the set of homogeneous pieces $g_k$ of $g=i(f)$in the nonstandard grading.

Comment: @ZachTeitler This doesn't appear to work. We want to show $P \in V$ if and only if $g_k \not\in P$ for some $k.$ Suppose $P$ is given and $g_k \not\in P,$ then $g \not\in P,$ so $f = \iota^{-1}(g) \not\in \iota^{-1}(P).$ But how do we show now that $P \in V$?